# postgresql: задать название столбца из select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Так могу задать название столбца `my_column`:

```
  select id_json, 
  body::json->'info'->'txt1'->0->>11 as my_column
  from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79;
```

Как взять название столбца из другой ветки этого json, например, так работает:

```
  select distinct body::json->'info'->'txt2'->>11
  from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79; // получаю нужное название столбца;
```

Так не получается:

```
... as (select distinct body::json->'info'->'txt2'->>11
         from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79)
from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79;


так тоже:

with col as (select distinct body::json->'info'->'txt2'->>11
              from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79)
select
id_json, 
body::json->'info'->'txt1'->0->>11
as col
from tbl where id_json > 70 AND id_json < 79;
```

Как такое присоседить?

Comment: Только динамическим SQL.

Comment: @Akina, понятно, спасибо.